# newInstance with arguments

Tags: reflection, scala

Is there any way to 'dynamically'/reflectively/etc create a new instance of a class with arguments in Scala?

For example, something like:

```
class C(x: String)
manifest[C].erasure.newInstance("string")
```

But that compiles. (This is also, rest assured, being used in a context that makes much more sense than this simplified example!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`erasure` is of type `java.lang.Class`, so you can use constructors (anyway you don't need manifest in this simple case - you can just use `classOf[C]`). Instead of calling `newinstance` directly, you can at first find correspondent constructor with `getConstructor` method (with correspondent argument types), and then just call `newInstance` on it:

```
classOf[C].getConstructor(classOf[String]).newInstance("string")
```