# Calling a constructor through java reflection in scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Before Scala 2.10 I had

```
class A {
    class B(b: Int) {
    }
}
```

and somewhere in code recreate class B with

```
val bCtor = bInstance.getClass.getConstructor(classOf[Int])
bCtor.newInstance ...
```

and everything was fine. It was with signature `public A$B(Int)`

Now constructor have 2!!! arguments. It has a new signature `public A$B(A,Int)`. What is argument with type A? I don't have access to A class from my function. It there any workaround?

For example [newInstance with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366057/newinstance-with-arguments) - It doesn't work anymore for inner class

Comment: Note that adding `A` as the first constructor argument is also the way it works in Java (http://jroller.com/tomdz/entry/reflection_inner_classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be carful not to confuse java inner class with scala path-dependent type
(from the [Programming In ScalaBook](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed%20%22Progamming%20In%20Scala%20Book%22%29)) :

> A path-dependent type resembles the syntax for an inner class type in Java, but there is a crucial difference: a path-dependent type names an outer **object**, whereas an inner class type names an outer **class**

So in your case bInstance is related to an aInstance.

My assumption is that aInstance is the object passed as the first parameter to this constructor.

Comment: I want to recreate some class (include inner) with reflection. Before 2.10 I have such ability. Sad :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use an unconstrained self-type annotation to have a way to refer to the A's version of `this` even from within B (where `this` now refers to the B instance).

```
package rrs.scribble

object  OuterInner {
  class Outer { oThis =>
    class Inner {
      def identify { printf("I am %s; I'm inside of %s%n", this, oThis) }
    }
    val inner = new Inner
  }

  def oiTest {
    val o1 = new Outer
    o1.inner.identify
  }
}
```

In the REPL:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).

scala> import rrs.scribble.OuterInner._
import rrs.scribble.OuterInner._

scala> oiTest
I am rrs.scribble.OuterInner$Outer$Inner@63d0d313; I'm inside of rrs.scribble.OuterInner$Outer@22d1b797
```

Answer (score 1):

First, adding `A` as the first constructor argument is also the way it works in Java:

> > [If this Class object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

Second,

> What is argument with type A? I don't have access to A class from my function.

If you have a `B` (as seems from your example), then you can [access its enclosing instance](http://jroller.com/tomdz/entry/reflection_inner_classes) (it doesn't seem to be documented officially, and so may change in the future versions of Java):

```
val aInstance = bInstance.getClass.getDeclaredField("this$0").get(bInstance)
bCtor.newInstance(aInstance, ...)
```

If you don't, then you can't create a `B` (without an `A`), but you shouldn't be able to. What would you expect this code to return?

```
class A(foo: Int) {
  class B {
    def bar = foo
  }
}

classOf[A#B].getConstructor().newInstance().bar
```

Comment: Thank you. Right. Actually is was a copy constructor, so I didn't worry about closures. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

@evantill is right, the only constructor of `B` is `A$B.<init>(A, Int)`. So `bInstance.getClass.getConstructor(classOf[A], classOf[Int])` works.

Comment: Most annoying thing that I used universal constructor in trait before 2.10 with getClass(). IMHO now I must implement something like builder pattern. So I hope that there maybe some trick that solve this new behavior.